# Different output with different pc

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm running an algorithm that I wrote on two different computers.
on one computer i get the result that i want but in the other it prints:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "argument is not interpretable as
>   logical"

i don't understand why is this happening.. i copied the same code from the pc that it works, I tried to: delete all the packages, uninstall R Studio, clean the global environment but nothing works..
any suggestions? 
the part of the code that i want to run is this:

```
> m.list.2var <- list() l <- 1 for (i in models)    {   for (j in
> c(2:ncol(eu))) 
>     {
>     for (k in c(2:ncol(eu))) 
>       {
>       if (j >= k) next
>       
>       cl <- makeCluster(4)
>       registerDoParallel(cl)
>       set.seed(503)
>       m.list.2var[[l]] <- train( eu[, c(j,k)], eu[, 1], method = i, trControl = timecontrol, tuneGrid = get(paste0(i, "Grid")) )
>       stopCluster(cl)
>       
>       l <- l + 1
>       cat(l, ".", i, "[", j, k, "]\n")
>     }   } }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the problem.
i didn't have the newest version of r (3.3.1) in the pc that it didn't work.
hope that will help others.